# SearchBar on submit

Tags: javascript, mobile, typescript, nativescript

I'm trying to get the events of the search bar, but there is no answer...
It is necessary to do something more?

ts:

```
import {CompaniesViewModel} from "../../shared/models/companyModel";
import {Page} from "ui/page";
import {SearchBar} from "ui/search-bar";

export function pageLoaded(args) {
    console.log('pageLoaded');
    var page = <Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new CompaniesViewModel();

    var searchBar = new SearchBar();
    searchBar.on(SearchBar.submitEvent, function (args) { 
        console.log("Search for " + (<SearchBar>args.object).text);
    });
    searchBar.on(SearchBar.clearEvent, function (args) {
        console.log("Clear");
    });
}
```

xms:

```
<SearchBar row="1" text="{{ search }}" hint="NIF ou Nome da empresa" id="search" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `searchBar` variable is initialized with a new `SearchBar` and has nothing to do with your search bar defined in XML. So your TS should be changed to:

```
import {CompaniesViewModel} from "../../shared/models/companyModel";
import {Page} from "ui/page";
import {SearchBar} from "ui/search-bar";

export function pageLoaded(args) {
    console.log('pageLoaded');
    var page = <Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new CompaniesViewModel();

    var searchBar = page.getViewById<SearchBar>("search");
    searchBar.on(SearchBar.submitEvent, function (args) { 
        console.log("Search for " + (<SearchBar>args.object).text);
    });
    searchBar.on(SearchBar.clearEvent, function (args) {
        console.log("Clear");
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you! :D I'm beginning to understand the logic: P